# Excel: Trouble graphing 3 sets of data properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I've got this table:

```
Name   Tech   NotTech   TechToNotTechRatio
Abc    115    121       0.95
Bca    127    186       0.68
Cab    135    160       0.84
Cba    149    196       0.76
Bac    142    185       0.77
Acb    148    221       0.67
Aaa    186    200       0.93
Bbb    227    249       0.91
Ccc    241    360       0.67
Abb    289    457       0.63
```

And this list continues up to 33 rows. I want to design a chart in which Tech and NotTech columns will be displayed as vertical bars (or cylinders or pyramids). The last column (That is their ratio) should be a line or something over them (Just to give my customer a visualized sense of the ratio alongside plain numbers of technicians and non-technicians). This is what I get when I try it normally by selecting these data sets:

My excel graph that the third set of data is not shown properly:

[image: My excel graph that the third set of data is not shown properly.]

As you can see the third set cannot be seen because of its very small values comparing to other columns. How can I correct it?

Comment: The vertical bars next to each other are already a much more intuitive indicator of the ratio than any line you could add.  The line will detract, unless the purpose is to put everything on the same scale relative to 100%.  Too much detail on a chart is visually confusing.  You are usually better off picking either the values or the ratio, and plotting one or the other.  But if you need both, use a second scale for the ratio.  You would have the scale for the bars on the left axis, and the scale for the ratio on the right axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a `Combo` chart, use `Clustered Column` for "Tech" and "NotTech", `Line` for "TechToNotTechRatio" and check off `Secondary Axis`. You should see what you describe and see that @fixer1234 is right: the line is distracting at best.

[image]